# Does windows phone8 sdk support winjs

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I used C# develop a WP7 app. I'm wondering if the Windows Phone 8 SDK supports WinJS? If so, I will move to WinJS for WP and WinRT both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can develop an app with HTML5 running in a WebBrowser, but without WinJS. You can use C# on both platforms though. No reason to use WinJS.

Comment: Does MS have the future plan to add winjs for wp8?

Comment: I don't know. MS does not discuss its future plans in public and SO is not a speculation engine.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, Windows Phone 8 only supports the Silverlight UI technologies. That is, .NET languages and XAML.

Comment: just to clarify for those seeing the response and not taking it in the correct context: you CAN build Windows Phone 8 applications other ways, including native C++ and HTML5. The HTML5/JavaScript approach is, however, a 'web application' paradigm (and you might use PhoneGap or Sencha, for instance). It's not the same model as WinJS on Windows 8 (which is what Claus was referring to)

Comment: C++/CX is NATIVE. It is NOT a .NET language.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be old, but things have changed as Microsoft is announcing at BUILD 2014 that WinJS is now included in the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK as well.

[Build 2014 WinJS on Phone](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-506)